# mysqldump entire database/s

Tags: database, backup, mysql

Recently I used mysqldump to backup a database without any option, and when I open it with MySQL Workbench I only have the database without relationships on EER Diagram, views, etc.
How to use mysqldump to backup entire database?

Thanks.

Comment: EER diagrams are part of MySQL Workbench Models (.mwb), there aren't part of MySQL database.

Comment: I imported the sql script and used reverse enginyering to create the EER Diagram, tables and rows appear but seems mysqldump dind't save the relations, views, etc

Comment: I tried with --skip-opt but it generates a  very large .sql, unable to import that monster.

Comment: --skip-opt will disable default params  --add-drop-table --add-locks --create-options --disable-keys --extended-insert --lock-tables --quick --set-charset. Skipped command --extended-insert means every row in database will have own INSERT command, so the SQL file will be much greater then with default --opt parameter.